# Removing Null Values from a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that will return countries that had exports of over "500" from my database.  My issue is that instead of not returning countries that do not meet the criteria, my query still returns those countries except with null as the export value.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(TradeInfo.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
SELECT Country.CountryName
FROM Country INNER JOIN TradeInfo ON Country.CountryID = TradeInfo.CountryID
WHERE (((TradeInfo.year)=2000) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export") AND ((TradeInfo.Amount)>=500)) OR (((TradeInfo.year)=2013) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export")) AND ((TradeInfo.Amount)>=500)
GROUP BY Country.CountryName, TradeInfo.Amount
PIVOT TradeInfo.Year;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to check out http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/ particular #4 which checks for NULL values.

Comment: @adammaus I have actually already seen that article.  I am trying to prevent lines with values under 500 from appearing at all.

Comment: Have you tried adding an another criteria to your WHERE clause that excludes the NULL export values. Something like: TradeInfo.CountryID IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

WHERE (((TradeInfo.year)=2000) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export") AND ((TradeInfo.Amount)>=500)) OR (((TradeInfo.year)=2013) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export")) AND ((TradeInfo.Amount)>=500)

use 
WHERE (((TradeInfo.year)=2000) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export") AND (((TradeInfo.year)=2013) AND ((TradeInfo.Tradetype)="export")) AND ((TradeInfo.Amount)>=500) and (TradeInfo.Amount)>=500